# How do I extract content from a textfile with multiline regex in powershell?

Tags: regex, powershell, multiline

I have a file called list1.txt which contains

```
192.168.1.1

|root:pass\x0Droot\x0Dvizxv\x0Dadmin\x0D888888\x0Dxmhdipc\x0Ddefault\x0Djuantech\x0D123456\x0D54321\x0Dsupport\x0Droot/\x0Dpassword\x0D12345\x0Duser\x0Dadmin/\x0Dpass\x0Dadmin1234\x0D1111\x0Dsmcadmin\x0D666666\x0D1234\x0Dklv123\x0Dservice\x0Dsupervisor\x0Dguest\x0Dubnt\x0Dklv1234\x0DZte521\x0Dhi3518\x0Djvbzd\x0Danko\x0Dzlxx.\x0D7ujMko0vizxv\x0D7ujMko0admin\x0Dsystem\x0Dikwb\x0Ddreambox\x0Drealtek\x0D00000000\x0D1111111\x0Dmeinsm\x0Dtech\x0Ddefault\x0DS2fGqNFs\x0Dtelnet\x0Dhunt5759\x0DOxhlwSG8\x0Djauntech\x0Dantslq\x0Dusuario\x0Doracle\x0Dtor\x0D1001chin\x0D12341234\x0D20080826\x0D5up\x0D88888888\x0DGM8182\x0DROOT500\x0Dabc123\x0Dahetzip8\x0Dascend\x0Dblender\x0Dcat1029\x0Dchangeme\x0Ddownload\x0Dgrouter\x0Dh3c\x0Dhg2x0\x0Dhuigu309\x0DiDirect\x0Dipcam_rt5350\x0Diwkb\x0Dnflection\x0Dnmgx_wapia\x0Doelinux123\x0Dprivate\x0Dsolokey\x0Dsvgodie\x0Dswsbzkgn\x0Dt0talc0ntr0l4!\x0DtaZz@23495859\x0Dtelecomadmin\x0Dtl789\x0Dtsgoingon\x0Dtwe8ehome\x0Dwin1dows\x0Dxc3511\x0Dzhongxing\x0Dzsun1188\x0Dtelnetadmin\x0D-
```

How can I make it formatted like this?

```
192.168.1.1:root:pass
```

Comment: is that ALL that the file contains?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey There is multiple like that in the same file.

Comment: Open a text editor, delete the two line breaks, the `|` and the rest of the second line?

Comment: @KevinChar - please, post a realistic sample - with at least 2 blocks of the text from your input AND the text you want from each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might do it:

```
Get-Content .\list1.txt -Raw | Select-String '(?smi)(\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3})[^\|]*\|(\w+)\:(\w+)' -AllMatches | ForEach-Object {$_.Matches} | ForEach-Object {"$($_.Groups[1].Value):$($_.Groups[3].Value):$($_.Groups[4].Value)"}
```

The output looks like this, if I put your content into a file twice:

> 192.168.1.1:root:pass
>
> 192.168.1.1:root:pass

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following using the switch statement:

```
switch -regex -file list1.txt {
    '^192\.168\.1\.\d+$' { $ip = $_ }
    '^\|(.*?:.*?)\\x0D' { "{0}:{1}" -f $ip,$matches[1] }
}
```

This will work for cases where multiple credential lines are listed under an IP and when there are multiple blocks of IPs and credential lines.

`^192\.168\.1\.\d+$` matches lines that contain only an IP `192.168.1.x` where `x` is any number. `^\|(.*?:.*?)\\x0D` matches `|non-colon chars:non-backslash chars\x0D` that begins a line. The `non-colon chars:non-backslash chars` match is capture group `1`, which is referenced as `$matches[1]` in the code.